# Subtle mistakes of one implementation of decision stump

Tags: python, machine-learning, decision-tree

Note: this question arises because of implementation details instead of decision stump ERM algorithm itself.

I am trying to implement the decision stump algorithm by myself and compare it with a *correct* implementation (both implementations are shown below).

To my understanding, my implementation is essentially the same as the correct implementation, where I do the sorting of `x`, `D` and `y` together but correct implementation does not sort `D` and `y` and uses `curr_idx` instead.

But after running the following test codes, of 10000 different test cases, I got 6213 incorrect test cases.

```
np.random.seed(0)
cor_count = 0
err_count = 0
for iter in range(10000):
    X = np.random.randint(1, 100, size=(10, 2))
    D = np.random.rand(10)
    D /= np.sum(D)
    y = np.random.choice([-1, 1], size=(10,))
    my_res = my_decision_stump(X, D, y)
    res = decision_stump(X, D, y)
    if my_res == res:
        cor_count += 1
    else:
        err_count += 1

print("Number of correct cases {}".format(cor_count))
print("Number of error cases {}".format(err_count))
```

My implementation and correct implementation are shown below.

```
def my_decision_stump(X, D, y):
    Fs = np.inf

    optimal_j = None
    optimal_b = None
    optimal_theta = None

    m, d = X.shape
    for j in range(d):
        record = np.hstack((X[:, j].reshape(-1, 1), D.reshape(-1, 1), y.reshape(-1, 1)))
        record_sorted = record[record[:, 0].argsort()]
        x = record_sorted[:, 0]; D = record_sorted[:, 1]; y = record_sorted[:, 2]
        x = np.hstack((x, x[-1]+1))

        F_pos = np.sum(D[y == 1])
        F_neg = np.sum(D[y == -1])

        if F_pos < Fs or F_neg < Fs:
            optimal_theta = x[0] - 1; optimal_j = j
            if F_pos < F_neg:
                Fs = F_pos; optimal_b = 1
            else:
                Fs = F_neg; optimal_b = -1

        for i in range(m):
            F_pos -= y[i] * D[i]
            F_neg += y[i] * D[i]
            if (F_pos < Fs or F_neg < Fs) and x[i] != x[i+1]:
                optimal_theta = 0.5 * (x[i] + x[i+1]); optimal_j = j
                if F_pos < F_neg:
                    Fs = F_pos; optimal_b = 1              
                else:
                    Fs = F_neg; optimal_b = -1       
    return (optimal_j, optimal_b, optimal_theta)

def decision_stump(X, D, y):
    Fs = np.inf

    optimal_j = None
    optimal_b = None
    optimal_theta = None

    m, d = X.shape
    for j in range(d):
        index = np.argsort(X[:, j])
        x = np.zeros(m+1)
        x[:-1] = X[index, j]
        x[-1] = x[-2] + 1
        F_pos = np.sum(D[y == 1])
        F_neg = np.sum(D[y == -1])
        if F_pos < Fs or F_neg < Fs:
            optimal_theta = x[0] - 1; optimal_j = j
            if F_pos < F_neg:
                Fs = F_pos; optimal_b = 1                   
            else:
                Fs = F_neg; optimal_b = -1

        for i in range(m):
            curr_idx = index[i]
            F_pos -= y[curr_idx] * D[curr_idx]
            F_neg += y[curr_idx] * D[curr_idx]
            if (F_pos < Fs or F_neg < Fs) and x[i] != x[i+1]:
                optimal_theta = 0.5 * (x[i] + x[i+1]); optimal_j = j
                if F_pos < F_neg:
                    Fs = F_pos; optimal_b = 1              
                else:
                    Fs = F_neg; optimal_b = -1       
    return (optimal_j, optimal_b, optimal_theta)
```

I am not sure what (maybe subtle) mistake I have made.
Could anyone help me, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I made a stupid mistake...

In my implementation, due to the abuse of variable name `D` and `y`, it turns out that every time `D` and `y` changes (i.e. `D = record_sorted[:, 1]` but in next iteration this `D` is used, the same with `y`) since I do the sorting but they SHOULD NOT.

This example shows the great hazard of abusing variable name.